# Automatically show tableFooterView if numberOfRowsInSection is zero?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

That is:

```
if ([self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] == 0) {
    self.tableView.tableFooterView.hidden = NO;
} else {
    self.tableView.tableFooterView.hidden = YES;
}
```

But I hope it can update automatically.

Comment: return height and view(if it's a custom) of footer as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I put the show/hide `tableFooterView` logic into:

`- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section`

It works well for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement this function :

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if ([tableView numberOfRowsInSection:section] == 0) return ***height***;
    else return 0;
}
```